# Java Array of Linked Lists

Tags: java

I am trying to code a custom hashtable which can allows multiple values.

We are doing it in following way:

1. Create an array of Linked Lists of the size Integer_MAX (custom linked list).
2. Insert values (int's) to the Linked Lists whose number is key number.

Means structure like:

```
value1 -> value6
NULL
Null
value3 -> value7
Null
...
...(until Int-Max)
```

Now, as we will store nearly 500 millions of key value pairs, at-lest 1600 millions link lists are going to be wasted.

Now, as per suggestion fro my working place, I am trying to build hashtable with structure like:

```
1 -> value1 -> value6
0
0
1 -> value3 -> value7  // here 0/1 bit defines linked lists exits or not
0
...
...(until Int-Max)
```

Can anybody help me is this possible to build such kind of structure ?

Edit:

1. [Why we are trying to do this can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765517/java-custom-hash-map-table-some-points)
2. Current code (by [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman)) can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/3230417).

Answer (score 1):

You can not create an array of generic type because array is reified type. Generics are implemented by erasure.

Comment: Try to use ArrayList. It should work with performance close enought to array.

Comment: But if I define arraylist(Int-Max) it will affect same like array. Sorry, even more as object.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what exactly do you want to do. Do you want to reduce number of `null` links in current implementation? Do you want to store link only by some condition?

Comment: yah. But, without reducing the size from Int-Max (means O(1) complexity) because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765517/java-custom-hash-map-table-some-points.

Comment: I can propose to use abstract node class `CustomHashMap.AbstractNode` with 2 subclasses - `CustomHashMap.EmptyNode` and `CustomHashMap.NotEmptyNode`. `CustomHashMap.EmptyNode` should be singleton with no data inside. So, you will have additional instance check, but reduce memory usage. Correct me if I am wrong or did not understand your problem again, please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14801/discussion-between-gkuzmin-and-arpssss)